# Adding Image in a Recycler View

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to add image in a recycler view - after getting it from gallery. (In a Chat App using Firebase)

Also, in the code...
`recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);`

Next,
there is a message adapter set into the recycler view using `.setAdapter()`

I am unable to figure out where to add the image view in xml. I added it in the recycler view, added the code but on running the app, it crashes.

The code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getimage();
            }
        });
```

```
    void getimage(){

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == 1) {


                imageUri = data.getData();
                imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
            }
        }
    }
```

So, where should I add the image view in the xml.
Are there any errors in the code, should I change it?

Thanks.

Comment: this codes are not the point. please show the error message and adapter code

Answer (score 0):

You should add it to your list of messages in the Adapter something like `adapter.addToList(image)`. Where the function in the Adapter looks like this:

```
fun addToList(imageUri: Uri) {
   messageList.add(imageUri)
   adapter.notifyItemInserted(messageList.size-1)
}
```

Since you mentioned Firebase, I think you should have a look in this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0).